# Attempted Analogy between Taylor and Fourier Series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series

The coefficient of each term in a Taylor series describes the series' nth derivative as aligning with that of the function $f(x)$ it aims to describe. What aspect of the function $g(x)$ a Fourier series aims to describe does its coefficient represent?

I understand that a Fourier series's coefficients represent its alignment with its sinusoidal component of "$n$-th frequency," which is analogous in one sense to how a Taylor series' coefficient describes the degree to which an nth-degree monomial is represented in a function. However, that's a different relationship to what I'm asking about and is the only thing I've found so far in my research. I've noticed that a Fourier coefficient is like an average over a circle, which I think is on the right track, but I can't figure out what property of the original function it represents.

Comment: The analogy is in approximating a function with certain types of functions (polynomials for Taylor series) and trigonometric polynomials for Fourier series. Taylor series approximation is of local nature, Fourier series is of global (or in average) nature (pointwise convergence is more delicate).

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're searching for. Fourier series coefficients/Fourier transforms represent the amplitude (and phase) of a sinusoidal (or complex exponential) component of the function, at a given frequency. There are other analogous ways you can cast this, but it all fundamentally comes back to that.

Comment: Both series use sums of simpler functions to approximate a more complex function, but the coefficients provide a reason for why that particular approximation is correct. In the case of a Taylor series, it's because those coefficients preserve the given function's unique nth derivatives, and that's what determines to what degree an nth-degree polynomial is expressed in the actual function. What I'm wondering is what property the Fourier coefficients express about the original function that makes that representation the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Glossing over some non-trivial convergence details, both developments are computing the projection of a function over an (infinite dimension) vector space representing (most of the common) univariate functions.

In the case of the Fourier series, the basis used is something like $e^{inx}$. In the case of the Taylor expansion, the basis is $x^n$.

There are other differences but this is how I find it intuitive.